# How to remove border from quadrant lines in geom_point plot (ggplot2) after adding "size"

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to remove border from quadrant lines in `geom_point` plot (ggplot2) after adding "size"?

```
ggplot(
  DurablesSIZE,
  aes(
    x = DurablesSIZE$`GDP LQ`,
    y = DurablesSIZE$Slope,
    color = DurablesSIZE$Sector,
    size = DurablesSIZE$`2019 GDP`
  )
) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1) +
  xlim(0, 5.5) +
  ylim(-0.26, 0.26) +
  geom_rect(aes(
    xmin = 1,
    xmax = Inf,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = Inf
  ),
  fill = "green",
  alpha = 0.03) +
  geom_rect(aes(
    xmin = -Inf,
    xmax = 1,
    ymin = -Inf,
    ymax = 0
  ),
  fill = "red",
  alpha = 0.03) +
  geom_rect(aes(
    xmin = -Inf,
    xmax = 1,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = Inf
  ),
  fill = "yellow",
  alpha = 0.03) +
  geom_rect(aes(
    xmin = 1,
    xmax = Inf,
    ymin = -Inf,
    ymax = 0
  ),
  fill = "yellow",
  alpha = 0.03) +
  labs(y = "Slope of GDP LQ (5Y)",
       x = "2019 GDP LQ",
       color = "Sector",
       size = "2019 GDP") +
  ggtitle("Oregon Durable Manufacturing \nTargeting Potential (GDP)") +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = ifelse(Slope > 0 & LQ > 1, as.character(Sector), '')),
    hjust = 0,
    vjust = 0,
    size = 2.5,
    nudge_x = -0.07,
    nudge_y = 0.013
  ) +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(colour = NA, fill = NA),
        legend.box.background = element_blank())
```

After adding size to my points, there is a weird border around the quadrant line [weird border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCrWs.png).

Comment: To have a good [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), it is helpful to provide some of your data, which you can do with `dput(head(df))`.

Answer (score 1):

The `size` aesthetic is being applied globally, so it is creating a thick border around each `geom_rect` -- it controls border width for that geom.

To remove it, take size out of the global aes mapping and use `geom_point(aes(size = '2019 GDP')) +` to apply it to that layer alone.

Another note: if you use `geom_rect` for annotation purposes, it will be plotted once for each relevant line of your data, leading to massive overplotting and minimal control of `alpha`. It will be better to use `annotate("rect" ...)` for those, or to create a separate summary table which those layers can refer to so they only plot once.

Here's some fake data I made up so that I could run your code. Please include something like this in your questions.

```
DurablesSIZE <- tibble(
  `GDP LQ` = 0.5*(1:10),
  LQ = 10:1,
  Slope = 0.05*(-4:5),
  Sector = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 2),
  `2019 GDP` = 1:10
)
```

Result with original code:

[image]

Revision with size aesthetic only applied locally:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. Sorry about not including my data; first time posting here. I'll add it going forward.